# AWS Codebuild: Unknown runtime version named '5.0' of dotnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have my ASP.net core API targeting **Dot net 5.0**. Is anyone successful in deploying a dotnet 5 application on Amazon Linux platform using CI/CD approach with AWS CodeBuild?

I tried to use dotnet `latest` which resolve to version `3.1`. And, when I use the `5.0` in `buildspec.yml`, it errors. As [per the blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-5-on-aws/), it seems to be supported. But not sure how to install using `buildspec.yml`.

```
phases:   
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      dotnet: 5.0
```

[image: aws error]

Comment: I had to use Ubuntu in the platform instead Amazon Linux

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you get your error?

Answer (score 6):

It is not yet supported. From the blog linked:

> Support for targeting .NET 5 in AWS CodeBuild is coming soon.

There is also [more recent github issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/issues/401#issuecomment-738032643) showing that you can build your own **custom image** for CB, for dotnet:5.0.

The [latest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html) supported version is dotnet 3.1

Comment: Even 6 months later it's not available, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Apparently it's supported since January 8, 2021 [(source)](https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/releases/tag/21.01.08)

Using the following environment for CodeBuild does work to build .NET 5 applications:

- Managed image
- Operating system: Ubuntu
- Runtime: Standard
- Image: aws/codebuild/standard:5.0
- Imager version: Always use the latest image for this runtime version
- Environment type: Linux

---

Meanwhile in the buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      dotnet: latest
...
```